# "$expo start" not opening the metro bundler in chrome anymore

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

Running `expo start` used to automatically open a useful UI on the browser in regards to the Metro Bundler, and now it's gone from all the boilerplate apps, so I can only assume it's been dropped by expo itself?

The bundler runs on the terminal, but its features pale in comparison with this UI.

I've spent a good amount of hours googling this, and tried it in different laptops with different repos and boilerplate code.

**Has anyone found a solution to get this running once again?**

here's a screenshot of the intended result:

[image: Metro Bundler on Chrome at localhost:19002]

Answer (score 3):

I've raised this issue on the expo github repo, and apparently, Expo has officially annouced the deprecation of this feature.

Here's a link to the issue on github : [link](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/19069)

Here're a link to the announcement : [link](https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206)